# Flickering planes

Tags: three.js, webgl

I have an application with large 2D planes with textures, but I am experience some flickering problems.

It is possible to see the flickering problem here (planes are withouth textures): [EXAMPLE CODE](http://jsfiddle.net/GYQ5v/64/)

Is this depth buffer (z-buffer) precision issues or something else?

Is the solution to scale down everything, not to allow large planes/objects? What is the best practice?

I know that z near and far also influence the precision, so setting z near to 1000 fixes the flickering in this example.

The code:

```
/*
 * Scale = 1, no flickering. Scale = 1000, flickering. 
 */
  var scale = 1000;

  var scene = new THREE.Scene();

  var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1000, 1000000);
  camera.position.x = 0;
  camera.position.y = 0;
  camera.position.z = 100 * scale;
  var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
      antialias: false
  });
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  var light = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xFFFFFF);
  scene.add(light);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      transparent: false,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      fog: false,
      color: 0xFFFF00,
      opacity: 1.0
  });

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(50 * scale, 50 * scale, 1, 1);
  var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
  cubeMesh.position.set(0, 0, 1 * scale);
  scene.add(cubeMesh);

  var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
      transparent: false,
      side: THREE.DoubleSide,
      fog: false,
      color: 0xFF0000,
      opacity: 1.0
  });

  var cubeGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(100 * scale, 100 * scale, 1, 1);
  var cubeMesh = new THREE.Mesh(cubeGeometry, material);
  scene.add(cubeMesh);

  function render() {
      var time = Date.now() * 0.5;
      camera.position.x = Math.sin(time / 1000) * 150 * scale;
      camera.position.y = 0;
      camera.position.z = Math.cos(time / 1000) * 150 * scale;
      camera.lookAt(scene.position);
      renderer.render(scene, camera);  
      requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  render();
```

Answer (score 43):

What you're seeing is the GPU running out of precision because the ranges you're using are too big. By setting the `near` plane of the camera to `100` (instead of `1`) the flickering is gone.

http://jsfiddle.net/GYQ5v/74/

Comment: Would you fix it the same way if you are working with loaded OBJs planes sitting litteraly on each other?

Comment: I tried setting near value to 100 and logarithmic depth buffer to true.Both didnt work for me in some models.Do you have any other suggestion.

Comment: I had the same problem with flickering shadows, I needed to set the `near` plane on my `Spotlight` to `100`.

Comment: Fixed for me as well. My plane was huge and when I shrank it, it fixed the issue

Answer (score 1):

Try out this code to see if it works:

```
cubeMesh.position.set(0, 0, 1);
```