# mesh looks incorrect (threejs r68)

Tags: three.js, rendering

I'm using threejs (R68) on the model online view project which converts some uploaded models to threejs files.
We found some models look incorrect as below.

[image: mesh incorrect]

Some models can be viewed at 
 http://www.threedbook.com/detail/23981

Especially when move the models(rotate or pan), the mesh color and shade look changing all the time.
Strange thing is that model will look normal if it's zoomed in enough size.
Would anyone point me which causes the rendering problem? or any issue when I convert the models to threejs file?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the similar issue at [Flickering planes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786723/flickering-planes) 
I make the near to 1, it works for most models.

Answer (score 1):

The modelling of the object is incorrect. You have overlapping polygons over the same area and very close to each other. When rendering, that would cause the appearance to change (specially if you are zoomed out since you dont have enough rendering resolution); ie. many polygons are squashed on top of each other and the renderer doesn't know which one to render first. When you zoom in, everything is ok because now you have the resolution.

Comment: sounds the conversion (model to threejs file) have some flaw. Most of models are ok, except some STEP and Solidworks models, such as http://www.threedbook.com/detail/23863.
Do you have any suggestion to fix the generated threejs files? Thanks!

Comment: as I said, it is up to the modelling of the models.

Comment: you mean the threejs file generation process, right?

Comment: well there are two steps in your pipeline. First model generation (how do you know the model has been created correctly in the modelling package). Second model conversion to three.js. Usually the translation/conversion process is not at fault. Usually it is the modelling of the object that is at fault.

Comment: I think the problems is because you are going from a solid model (.step, Solidworks) to a surface model / polygon model (Maya, Max). The way I usually overcome this is to open the model in Max, add the edit Poly modifier, fix what needs to be fixed, then export to .obj. You will then be able to convert to three.js file.

Comment: thanks gaitat @2pha, I'm trying to make the pipeline automaticlly, including fix the model

Comment: @2pha, it seems some solid models are ok in current conversion without any fix, e.g. http://www.threedbook.com/detail/24226. and some obj models also have this problem, e.g. http://www.threedbook.com/detail/5616