# Three.js: See through objects artefact on mobile

Tags: three.js

I recently tried my app on mobile and noticed some weird behavior, seems like camera near plane is clipping the geometry however other objects at the same distance aren't clipped... Materials are StandarMaterials, depthTest and depthWrite are set to true.

I must add I can't reproduce this issue on my desktop. Which makes it difficult to understand what's going on, since it's working perfectly at first sight.

Here are 2 gifs showing the problem:

[image: see through wall & floor]

You can see the same wall on the left in the next gif

[image: see through cabinet top]

Thanks!

#### EDIT:

It seems the transparent faces (on mobile) was due to `logarithmicDepthBuffer = true` (but don't know why?) and I also had additional artefacts cause by camera near and far planes being too far from each other producing depth issues (see [Flickering planes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792270/9670819))...

#### EDIT 2:

Well I wasn't searching for the right terms... Just found this today: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13047#issuecomment-356072043

So `logarithmicDepthBuffer` uses `EXT_frag_depth` which is only supported by 2% of mobiles according to [WebGLStats](https://webglstats.com/webgl/extension/EXT_frag_depth). A workaround would be to tesselate the geometries...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I wasn't searching for the right terms... Just found this today: https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/13047#issuecomment-356072043

So `logarithmicDepthBuffer` uses `EXT_frag_depth` which is only supported by 2% of mobiles according to [WebGLStats](https://webglstats.com/webgl/extension/EXT_frag_depth). A workaround would be to tesselate the geometries or stay with linear depth buffer...

Additional artefacts caused by camera near and far planes being too far from each other producing depth issues (see [Flickering planes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17792270/9670819))...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a logarithmic depth buffer to fix this. You've succumbed to the classic temptation to bring your near clip REALLY close to the eye and the far clip very far away. This creates a very non-linear depth precision distribution and is easily mitigated by pushing the near clip plane out by a reasonable amount. Try to sandwich your 3D data as tightly as possible between your near and far clip planes and tolerate some near plane clipping.