# a-sky jerky with oculus quest 2

Tags: aframe

Using a-framemin.js 1.3.0, a-sky with equirectangular pictures, and an oculus quest2, I get jerky (flickering) results on most of my pictures.

The problem is often at the bottom of the pano !
Center is OK !

I tried several image resolutions (4096x2048, 6080x3040, 8192x4096) -> same problem.

I tried picture resolution (72 dpi, 96 dpi) -> same problem

I tried different jpg compression rates (from 60% to 80 %) -> same problem

You can see some pictures [HERE](https://clatique.fr/multimedia/Themes/VR/theme-VR/)

a-frame or oculus q2 or something else might not like grass, roofs, lines.

The a-frame sphere is too small (rooms are wider than what is shown using my vr headset !)

**I don't know what to check now. I would really appreciate any help.**

I am studying a-frame a lot. Many webpages are outdated.

Note : I get a black screen on my computer when pressing the VR button.

Problem with 1920x1080 screen res.

Comment: did you try lower resolutions? is it happening when its 4k+, or even with 1024x512?

Comment: also check if small spheres work better than the a-sky, it might suggest [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17786723/flickering-planes)

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use smaller spheres, or resolutions, just trying to find the cause of the problem